# Additive Inverse of General Function

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I am told:

(i) Let $V $ be a real vector space and let $ x ∈ V $. Prove that its additive inverse is
unique.

(ii) Let now V be the vector space of real-valued functions defined on the interval $ [0, 1] $, and let
$ f ∈ V $. What is the additive inverse of $ f $ ?

I've done (I am extremely new to proof writing) for part (i):

Assume $b, c$ are additive inverses of $x$:

$x+b = 0 $

$x+c=0$

$b+0 = b+(x+c) = (b+x)+c \implies 0+c = b \implies c = b$

Using the inverse, zero vector and associativity axioms.

For part $(ii) $:

I am thinking for a real-valued function $f$ defined on $[0, 1]$, it's inverse would simply be $(-1)f$

$f + (-1)f = 0 \implies (1)f + (-1)f = 0 \implies (1-1)f \implies 0f = 0 \implies 0=0$

By the inverse, scalar multiplication and distributivity.

My primary question: have I massively oversimplified things? I see my proof writing needs (much) more formality. I would welcome feedback on that, or not. Thank you.

Comment: This question is well written. For that, +1. Also, the first part is correct, so well done.

Answer (score 1):

The proof of $(i)$ looks nice. For $(ii)$ not quite: You are asked to find what is the additive inverse of $f$, or equivalently what is $-f$. Your answer looks like "$-f=-f$", which is a tautology. They are asking you to, given $f$, find $-f$; i.e., find the function $g$ such that $f+g=0$. Now, to define a function you need to specify what is it that the function does with its argument. Can you take it from here?

Also, you write
$$f + (-1)f = 0 \implies (1)f + (-1)f = 0 \implies (1-1)f \implies 0f = 0 \implies 0=0$$
but that sequence of implications just proves $0=0$. What you need to do is claim which function is $-f$, and then compute $(f+\text{that function})(x)$ and check that this equals zero for every $x$.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out. I don't know that I can take it from there. I am not sure how to claim which function is the inverse of f since the argument of f is not specified. I understand the generality is the point, I'm just not there.

Comment: @Sofia No, then you are again saying "the additive inverse of $f$ is $-f$". You know that $f$ takes $x$ and produces $f(x)$ (which is not a function technically but a real number), so by knowing $f$ you know $f(x)$. Now you can claim that the function $g$ which takes $x$ into $-f(x)$ (i.e., $g(x)=-f(x)$) is the additive inverse of $f$. See? It might seem misleading at first because usually we abuse of notation and say things like "let $f(x)$ be the function blahblah" where we should say "let $f$ be the function (which takes $x$ into $f(x)$) blahblah". Makes sense now?

Comment: Thank you. So the idea would then be: $ (f+g)(x) = 0 => f(x)+g(x) = 0 => f(x) = -g(x) $ or $g(x) = -f(x) $?

Comment: @Sofia No, like I said, the first step is to claim which function is $g$. Now that you know that you need to check that $f+g=0$, or equivalently that $(f+g)(x)=0$ for every $x$. In these implications you are concluding that $g(x)=-f(x)$, but you already knew that since you defined $g$ that way. Just write what $(f+g)(x)$ means, you don't need to be implicating all the time.